# How can I compare ArrayList and String ignoring case?

Tags: java

I'm solving this [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAIeM.png)

My current working code is this:

```
// Importing the required packages.

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AbbreviationsDriver {

// Main method.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File abbreviationFile = new File("abbreviations.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(abbreviationFile);
        // ArrayList to save the messages in the file.
        ArrayList arrMessage = new ArrayList();
        String line;

        // read until last line
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanFile.nextLine();
            arrMessage.add(line);
        }

        // Input File Name
        System.out.print(" Enter the name of the original file :");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFileName = scanner.next();

        // Output File Name
        System.out.print("\n Enter the name of the new file :");
        String outputFileName = scanner.next();

        Scanner scanInputFile = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFileName));

        // Getting the line separator for the System.
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while (scanInputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String t;
            line = scanInputFile.nextLine();
            // Splitting on the basis of spaces.
            String[] temp = line.split(" ");
            // Adding the names to the ArrayList.
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                // if it is abbreviation, add <>
                if (arrMessage.contains(temp[i])) {
                    t = "<" + temp[i] + ">";
                }
                // if not, pass
                else {
                    t = temp[i];
                }
                // Write the string in the new file.
                out.write(t + " ");
            }
            // write new line
            out.write(newLine);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

abbreviation.txt:

```
lol
:)
iirc
4
u
ttfn
```

sample_msg.txt

```
How are u today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)
```

but when I try my code,

```
How are <u> today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>
```

Obviously, it did not filtered "Iirc" because it is capitalized.
But, I want to check whether String is in ArrayList 'ignoring cases'.
I searched internet, but I couldn't find the solution.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: try toLowerCase method https://www.baeldung.com/string/to-lower-case

Comment: Capitalized word(Iirc) is in ArrayList, so I can't use toLowerCase

Comment: convert all array list entries to lower case before comparing

Answer (score 0):

**List<T>.contains(T ..)** internally calls the "equals" method on T.

So your ArrayList contains will call the "equals" on String. That's why it's returning false when case doesnt match.

Several ways to deal with this:

1. Change all strings of arrMessage to Uppercase/Lowercase and while comparing use **temp[i].toUpperCase() or temp[i].toLowerCase()**
2. Create a wrapper around **String** and override the equals method to do equals ignore case.

---

edit: More on method 2

```
public class MyCustomStringWrapper {

  private String delegate;

  public MyCustomStringWrapper(String delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o)
      return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
      return false;
    MyCustomStringWrapper that = (MyCustomStringWrapper) o;
    return delegate.equalsIgnoreCase(that.delegate);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(delegate);
  }
}
```

```
public class AbbreviationsDriver {

// Main method.

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        File abbreviationFile = new File("abbreviations.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(abbreviationFile);
        // ArrayList to save the messages in the file.
        List<MyCustomStringWrapper> arrMessage = new ArrayList();
        String line;

        // read until last line
        while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanFile.nextLine();
            arrMessage.add(new MyCustomStringWrapper(line));
        }

        // Input File Name
        System.out.print(" Enter the name of the original file :");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFileName = scanner.next();

        // Output File Name
        System.out.print("\n Enter the name of the new file :");
        String outputFileName = scanner.next();

        Scanner scanInputFile = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFileName));

        // Getting the line separator for the System.
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        while (scanInputFile.hasNextLine()) {
            String t;
            line = scanInputFile.nextLine();
            // Splitting on the basis of spaces.
            String[] temp = line.split(" ");
            // Adding the names to the ArrayList.
            for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                // if it is abbreviation, add <>
                if (arrMessage.contains(new MyCustomStringWrapper(temp[i]))) {
                    t = "<" + temp[i] + ">";
                }
                // if not, pass
                else {
                    t = temp[i];
                }
                // Write the string in the new file.
                out.write(t + " ");
            }
            // write new line
            out.write(newLine);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

---

Edit:
Ok so here is another issue with the input text/code.

The **temp** array is being created by splitting the sample_message by ' ' (space) i.e it contains a string called "Iirc," and not "Iirc"

So you **also need to change the sample_msg.txt file** to this:

```
How are u today? Iirc , this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! :)
```

---

Since you cant change the sample_msg.txt file, you can change the splitting logic like this:

```
String[] temp = line.split("(\\s|,\\s)");
```

which means split by space or (comma and space)

But then in the output b.txt you will loose the comma.

```
How are <u> today? <Iirc> this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>
```

Comment: First method would be impossible because output.txt should contain original cases, not all lowered cases. Could you explain more about second method?

Comment: @JasonKim Please check on method2. I hope this suffices your case.

Comment: I tried this code, but same result happens. How are <u> today? Iirc, this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>

Comment: @JasonKim Bro it looks like a different problem, I debugged and found that temp arr contains the string called "Iirc," and not lirc . So its not working.

Comment: Aside from using the custom string wrapper you need to make this change to the sample msg also. Or we have to think of some other logic of splitting the sample message.

Comment: Hmm...that's what I'm absolutely not thinking about. Do you have any good idea about another spliting method?

Comment: Splitting with the regex String[] temp = line.split("(\\s|,\\s)"); will work but then since you are doing   out.write(t + " ");    The output becomes devoid of the comma.

How are <u> today? <Iirc>  this is your first free day. Hope you are having fun! <:)>

Answer (score 0):

Make all words in arrMessage small case:

```
// read until last line
while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
     line = scanFile.nextLine();
     arrMessage.add(line.toLowerCase());
}
```

While comparing, make your scanned word small case:

```
if (arrMessage.contains(temp[i].toLowerCase())) {
```

Comment: I try this way, but nothing changed

Comment: It is also problem when it works because the output.txt should be remained as original, not all lowered.